# Function defined with 'this', but executing without 'this'

Tags: javascript

I was expecting the 2nd call of the "taco" function to generate a runtime error since I am not calling it with the "this" keyword:

```
function foo() {
    var bar = "baz";

    this.taco = function() {
        console.log(bar);
    };
    this.taco();
    taco(); // I expected a runtime error here.     
}

foo();
```

However, it does not.

Here is a fiddle of the same code:  http://jsfiddle.net/phillipkregg/gdFxU/226/

Is JavaScript using some type of implicit context management here?

Just curious, thanks!

Comment: `this` means `window` unless it was called with `new`

Comment: Note that `this` is solely based on how you invoke a function, not how you define it

Answer (score 8, accepted):

The reason is that when you call `foo()`, you are invoking it in the scope of the `window` object.  That means that inside of `foo()`, the value of `this` is set to `window`.

Thus, `this.taco()` is actually `window.taco()` which is the same as `taco()`.  In other words, `taco()` is a global function so it works either way you call it as `taco()`, as `window.taco()` or as `this.taco()` when `this` is `window`.

If you involve `taco()` as a new object like this where `this` is set to a new instance of `foo` and is not equal to `window`, then you get the expected run-time error:

```
function foo() {
    var bar = "baz";

    this.taco = function() {
        console.log(this);
        console.log(bar);
    };
    this.taco();
    taco(); // I expected a runtime error here.     
}

var x = new foo();
```

Example: http://jsfiddle.net/jfriend00/3LkxU/

---

If you are confused about the value of `this`, there are these javascript rules that determine the value of `this`:

1. If you call a function with `new` like `x = new foo()`, then a new instance of `foo` is created and the value of `this` is set to that object inside the `foo()` function and that new instance is returned from `foo()` by default.
2. If you call any function normally like `foo()`, then the value of `this` is set to be the global object which in a browser is `window` or if in javascript's newer "strict" mode, then `this` will be `undefined`.  This is what was happening in your original example.
3. If you call a method with an object reference like `obj.foo()`, then `this` will be set to be the `obj` object.
4. If you make a function call with `.apply()` or `.call()`, then you can specifically control what the value of `this` is set to with the first argument to `.apply()` or `.call()`.  For example: `foo.call(obj)` would call the `foo()` function and set the `this` pointer to the `obj` object.
5. If you are not in any function call (e.g. at the global scope), then `this` will be either the Global object (`window` in a browser) or `undefined` in strict mode.
6. As in all of the above rules, `this` is controlled by how the caller calls you, not how the function/method is defined.

Comment: @PhillipKregg - I added to my answer an explanation of how `this` is set in javascript.

Answer (score 2):

The reason is `this` in foo(), when it's called just as is, will reference a global object. This means `taco` function will be introduced in the global scope.

To get the functionality you want use `new foo()` syntax instead. Then `this` will refer to a new object, which `taco` property will be assigned a new value (function). Calling `taco` directly will get you an error then.

Answer (score 1):

```
foo(); // equals window.foo() , `this` equals `window` and `this.taco` equals `window.taco` and `window.taco`  equals `taco` as it is global

new foo(); //creates a new object. this will give error because here `this.taco` is not `taco`
```