# Why does this JS var lose value after AJAX?

Tags: javascript, jquery, ajax

Consider this snippet:

```
$('.job-details-apply').live('click', function () {
    var url = $('#apply-job-url').val();
    var id = $(this).attr('value');
    var selected = $(this);
    $.ajax({
        url: url,
        data: { id: id },
        success: function (data) {
            $(selected).html('Test!');//selected is undefined at this point
        },
        error: function () {
        }
    });
    return false;
});
```

The `var` `selected` is undefined in the success handler. Do I need to scope it outside of the click function? e.g.

```
var selected = null;
$('.job-details-apply').live('click', function () {
    selected = $(this);
    //blah
}
```

Something doesn't seem right about that to me.

edit: If it makes a difference the value returned from the controller id a `JsonResult` (and at the moment it is simply just a bool)

Comment: off topic but i was told that `.live()` has been deprecated, replaced by `.on()` or `.delegate()`

Comment: Why does it return null? it should never return null, it should be either `undefined` or `not an object`, but never `null`.

Comment: I don't think `selected` is `undefined`, unless you are redeclaring it. How are you testing for the value and what are you doing inside the success handler?

Comment: Sorry yes you are right - it is undefined (will edit) (it is 3.10am here lol )

Comment: I cannot reproduce this issue in a test environment; using `console.log(selected.length)` I'm presented with `1`, meaning that the reference to the variable held in place. I used `.live()` even though it should be `bound to a static parent element` such as `$(document).on('click', '.job-details-apply', function(){ //code here });`. There must be another issue; have you checked your console to see if there's something playing a role on this that we're not privvy to? such as an ajaxSubmit function perhaps?

Comment: Is this all the code for this call? Are there any lines within that method that have been removed for simplicity? If so what are they?

Comment: The only line omitted (which I have now added in) was a call to insert some html - selected is undefined so it errors.

Comment: This isn't the problem, but `$(selected).html('Test!');` should just be `selected.html('Test!');` because `selected` is already a jQuery object.

Comment: Thanks for off topic tips (that kinda sounds sarcastic - it isn't meant to be) - all helps :)

Comment: Unable to replicate: http://jsfiddle.net/9RunF/

Comment: @Ohgodwhy OH GOD WHY DOES IT RETURN NULL?!

Answer (score 3):

You don't need to change how the `selected` variable is declared.  It will be available just fine in the success handler of your ajax function.

As a point of occasional confusion in jQuery ajax success handlers, but not the cause of this issue, the value of `this` will be different in your ajax success handler (it will point to an ajax object), but that will not affect access to the variables declared in your parent function since they are available directly without using `this`.

So, since what you're asking about is not a problem, if you are indeed having a problem with the `selected` variable, then the cause must be something else that you have not disclosed to us in the code you've shown so far.  We probably need to see a more complete example of where you have this problem or even a link to a working page so one can set a breakpoint and examine things.

Comment: Why the downvote?  There is nothing wrong with the syntax the OP asked about and I've answered that question that was posed.  Further, there is nothing else disclosed in the OP's code that would cause the problem the OP described so I've told them that.

Comment: -1: does not appear to be true: http://jsfiddle.net/Qt5sX/ . `foo`'s value does not change in different contexts, even when initialized as `this`.

Comment: @arxanas - your example illustrates  that `this` is is set by the browser before it calls the `onclick` error handler and it illustrates that `foo` maintains it's value in the callback (which is exactly what I said happens in my answer).  It doesn't disprove anything relative to what I've said in my answer.  So, I'm unsure what you've think you've proven or why you downvoted (if you did).

Comment: You say `The value of this will be different in your ajax success handler`, which is proven untrue by the callback.

Comment: @arxanas - if you understood anything about how `this` is set in javascript, you would know that the value of `this` is determined by the caller of a function or callback and how they call it.  So, the ajax situation in the OP's question is a completely different caller than your onclick handler so what happens in one has NOTHING to do with the other.  jQuery's ajax code sets `this` to point to the `jqXHR` object unless a specific context has been set in the ajax settings object.  An onclick handler sets `this` to point to the object that triggered the event.

Comment: @arxanas - See the rules at the end of [this answer](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/12042946/function-defined-with-this-but-executing-without-this/12043026#12043026) for how the value of `this` is controlled/set.

Comment: I did. None of them seemed relevant.

Comment: @arxanas: You showed yourself that `this` has a different value in the event handler (it refers to the `a` element instead of `window`). That is the reason why `this` is assigned to other variables, to be able to reference `this` in other contexts. I don't understand what you have a problem with. jfriend's answer is correct, although it might not solve the problem (but that's due to the poor question).

Comment: Considering that `selected` was not set in the new context, I cannot see why that would be relevant.

Comment: @arxanas: Now you totally lost me... fact is, there is nothing wrong with this answer.

Comment: @arxanas - if that's what you're objecting to, I've amended my answer so that the comment about `this` is just additional information meant to be educational which is all I ever intended for it to be.

Comment: @arxanas Are you implying that `selected`, `id` and `url` would have to be "set" somehow inside the success callback in order to be accessible? If so, that's not true.

Answer (score 0):

When you do

```
var selected = $(this);
```

`selected` is now a jQuery object built from the element you clicked  (`this` is the DOM object for the element you clicked; it doesn't have any jQuery methods; `selected` *does* get jQuery methods).

```
$.ajax({
    url: url,
    data: { id: id },
    success: function (data) {
        $(selected).html('Test!');//selected is undefined at this point
```

`selected` should certainly be defined at this point, since it's an outer variable incorporated into a closure. However, `$(selected)` resolves to an attempt to pass what's already a jQuery object into a jQuery constructor, and jQuery is probably getting a little confused, since a jQuery constructor is generally expecting to see a DOM object (convert to jQuery object), an HTML string (build a corresponding DOM fragment and convert to jQuery object), a function (run it when the DOM is loaded), or an extended CSS selector (convert it into a jQuery object that represents one or more elements in the page). So the result of `$(selected)` isn't officially defined.

Obviously if this is the source of the problem, changing the code to `selected.html(...)` should at least give a different result, and should preferably work.
        },

Answer (score -1):

Yes, need to store `this` in a variable.

```
$('.job-details-apply').live('click', function () {
  var url = $('#apply-job-url').val();
  var id = $(this).attr('value');
  var _this = this;
  $.ajax({
      url: url,
      data: { id: id },
      success: function (data) {
          $(_this).html('Test!');
      },
      error: function () {
      }
  });
  return false;
});
```

Comment: where are you getting the e.Data.AC from?

Comment: Your current answer is essentially the same as the original code.  You save `this` into `_this`.  They saved `$(this)` into `selected`.  Why do you think the OP's code wouldn't work, but yours would?

Comment: Sorry @glosrob, the event.data doesn't works for this. Need to store it in a variable.

Comment: I did not say that his code would not work. I am saying and showing what needs store the `this`. @jfriend00

Comment: Right, but jfriend00 is saying the code is equivalent; it doesn't matter what the name of it is.

Comment: This is the question: "Do I need to scope it outside of the click function?". This is the answer: "Yes, need to store this in a variable". What is wrong? Why the downvote?

Comment: Actually, the OP asked whether he has to declare the variable outside of the `.live` callback and the answer to that is no. His code should work fine.

Comment: @ShankarCabus I don't know, but probably because your code is the same. Whether you set selected to $(this) and use it in the callback, or set _this to this and use it in the callback, doesn't matter--it's the same thing. In the first case you're saving the JQ version of this, in the other you're saving this. What's the difference?

Comment: His code saves jQuery object: `selected = $(this)` and after uses `$(selected).html()` instead of `select.html()`.

Comment: @ShankarCabus Obviously; I just said that. It's not another selector, it's just redundant. It's not the issue.

Comment: Ok .. go ahead. The question was changing and just getting confused. My bad ;)