# Mouseout keeps firing continuously

Tags: javascript

So i have a function which assigns a mouseover, this adds a hover tooltip div and a mouseout event to the div that triggers it so i can remove the tooltip.

The problem is the mouseout event fires but keeps firing when ever i move the mouse anywhere outside of the div, so it fires many hundreads of times for every pixel movement of the mouse.

This is the set up:

```
function ToolTip(data)
{
    var div           =  createDiv();
        div.className = 'ToolTip';
        div.innerHTML = 'This is a tooltip!';

    addChild(div,document.body); // appends to given element
    this.addEventListener('mouseout',function(){removeToolTip(div);},false);
}
function removeToolTip(el)
{
    console.log('test');
    this.removeEventListener('mouseout',removeToolTip,false);
    removeDiv(el);  //removes perfectly fine
}


for(var i=0;i<data.length;i++)
{
 var div = document.getElementById('id'+i);
    (function(i){
        div.addEventListener("mouseover",function(){ToolTip(data[i]);},false);
    })(i);              
}
```

I do not understand why mouseout keeps firing, i get `test` in my console log so it should be removing the event listener. Where have i gone wrong?

Comment: `el.removeEventListener`

Comment: el is the tooltip the, the tooltip doesn't need mouse interaction

Comment: Aren't you trying to remove the `mouseout` event handler from the tooltip itself?

Comment: whats the difference between `this` and `el`. your logic seems pretty confused

Comment: No, i remove the tooltip when the mouseout occurs on the object i want to see the tooltip for :P The tooltip occurs far from where the mouse is hovering over the item in question there is no mouse interaction with it. The tooltip "hovers" over and removes when i mouseout. `this` is the item i want to view the tooltip for.

Comment: @Dave - you do not understand what `this` is set to.  It is NOT what you want it to be (feel free to `console.log(this)` and you'll be surprised).  That is at least one of your problems.

Comment: I see so at some point `this` is no longer the element from the start but is now the window. Thats a pain, thought it would just keep inheriting.

Comment: http://jsfiddle.net/r3wt/4Dake/

Comment: @r3wt Is that jquery? I tend to go library free with my web development :P But thats for the link !

Comment: @Dave yep, it sure is. no prob, just killin time here(avoiding the odesk disaster that just got dropped in my lap)

Comment: lol :P this is my fiddle. http://jsfiddle.net/HDrPS/ still working out how to reference the function for mouse out but i removed the use of `this`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your event handling logic is pretty confused.

First off, you're adding a mouseover event handler to each of a series of divs.

Then, each time that mouseover event is triggered (which can be many times), you are calling `ToolTip()` which adds a mouseout event on `this` which appears to be the `window` object because `ToolTip()` is just a plain function call so `this` will either be the global object or `undefined` (in strict mode).

Then, in `removeToolTip()`, you are trying to call `removeEventListener('mouseout', ...)`, but that won't work because you're passing a different function to it than the `addEventListener()` used.  `removeEventListener()` requires that you pass in the exact same function that you passed to `addEventListener()` or it won't do anything.  So, since you're passing a different function, nothing is removed and you get a build-up of mouseout events and all on the window object.

Structurally, you need to fix:

1. Make sure you're installing the event handler on the correct object.  `this` in your functions is NOT what you want it to be.  I would suggest you stop using `this` in those functions and pass in the object you want to operate on as an argument to those functions.
2. Pass in an actual named function (not an anonymous function) to `addEventListener()` so you can later use it with `removeEventListener()`.
3. When you call `removeEventListener()` you must pass the exact same named function reference that you used with `addEventListener()`.
4. Make sure you're trying to call `removeEventListener()` on the right object also.

For more info on how `this` is set in a function call, see the five numbered points in [this prior answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/12043026/816620).

Comment: Well i loop the divs and add mouseover because each div will have a tooltip with different info displayed which is why i pass `data[i]` for event listener. I'm not sure i understand your second point though how do i pass the reference through, i thought `this` did that?

Comment: @Dave - `this` is NOT preserved when you call a function - it is changed based on how the function is called.  I'd suggest you just create an argument for your `ToolTip()` function and pass the object you want to operate on to it just like you do with `removeToolTip()`.  Then, stop using `this` on both those functions.

Comment: Yeah but in the script `this` is always the same div (the ones i create in the for loop) so i'm just passing it on with the use of `this` based on the console log it is the correct element. Its just mouseout keeps on going for some reason, its confusing my brain xD

Comment: @Dave - calling a function like when you call `ToolTip()` does NOT pass on the value of `this`.  Do a `console.log(this)` inside of `ToolTip()`.  You will find it is the `window` object (if you're not running in strict mode).

Comment: Ah yeah i see now it suddenly becomes `window` rather than the element thats a pain, so i have to put pass the element in the function aswell then.

Comment: @Dave - yes, that's what I've recommended in my answer (the point #1 in my answer).  You also have to stop using `this` in your `removeToolTip()` function because it has the same issue.  It appears you are already passing in the desired object there so you can just switch to using it.

Comment: @Dave - I'd suggest you read the five numbered points in [this linked answer](http://stackoverflow.com/a/12043026/816620) about how the `this` pointer is set in Javascript for any function call.

Comment: @Dave - do you also understand the other part about why `removeEventListener()` wasn't working - that you aren't passing in the right function reference?

Comment: no i think thats the part i'm most confused on... i've ditched the use of `this` and now just carry the elements in the functions but the remove listener doesn't actually remove.

Comment: @Dave - please see points 2 and 3 in my answer about `removeEventListener()`.  You must pass the exact same function reference to both `addEventListener()` and `removeEventListener()` for the remove to work.  You are passing different functions.

Comment: Hmm this is confusing i'm going to have to search for some code examples and see if i can get it to work on jsfiddle. Thanks for the help :)